# Combining mouse click and enter key press in the same event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a div that I made focusable with tabindex, and I want it to act like a button, doing something on both mouse click and enter key press. Can you do this with a single event listener, combining the following into one?

```
document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("click");
});
document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log("click");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put the `events` to handle in an Array and use `forEach` to add the event listener to the element.

```html
<div tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #f0f"></div>
<script>
var div = document.querySelector('div');
["click", "keypress"].forEach(ev=>{
  div.addEventListener(ev, function(e){
     if(ev=="click"){
       console.log("click");//clicked
     }
     if(e.keyCode==13){
      console.log("click");//enter key pressed
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

You can also define a function that both of the event listeners call.

```html
<div tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #f0f"></div>
<script>
var div = document.querySelector('div');
["click", "keypress"].forEach(ev=>{
  div.addEventListener(ev, handleEvent);
});
function handleEvent(e){
 if(e.type=="click"){
    console.log("click");//clicked
  }
  if(e.keyCode==13){
   console.log("click");//enter key pressed
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use two listeners, but as you have to pass a function to the listener which is called and gets all the necessary arguments you can create a single function for both cases like this:

```
function handleEvent(e){
   if(e //make sure a mouseEvent has been passed as argument
       &&
      e.keyCode === 13 //check for the correct key
   ){
      console.log("click");
   }
}

document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("click", handleEvent);
document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("keyup", handleEvent);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I thinks this is the best answer

<form>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="Some text.." value="">
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }
});
</script>
```